# Finding the substring in an input string

Tags: string, assembly, x86-16, strstr

I have this assembly program where I need to find the substring in the main string I input. My problem is that it always outputs the "word found" even if I typed two completely different words.  I don't know which part of my loop or condition is wrong. Please help me figure it out. Also, please suggest some string instructions that could be used in checking for a substring so that I can shorten my code. I am really confused with how the `cmpsb` works, I only tried to use it. Btw, I don't know how to use a debugger that's why I can't debug my code and I am just a newbie in assembly language.

Below is the logic part of my code.

```
.data
     prompt1 db "Input String: $"
     prompt2 db 10,10, 13, "Input Word: $"
     prompt3 db 10,10, 13, "Output: $"
     found db "Word Found. $"
     notfound db "Word Not Found. $"
     invalid db 10,10, 13, "Invalid. $"
     InputString db 21,?,21 dup("$")  
     InputWord db 21,?,21 dup("$")
     actlen db ?
     strlen dw ($-InputWord)

.code
start:
      mov ax, @data
      mov ds, ax
      mov es, ax

     ;Getting input string
     mov ah,09h
     lea dx, prompt1
     int 21h

     lea si, InputString
     mov ah, 0Ah
     mov dx, si
     int 21h

     ;Getting input word
     mov ah,09h
     lea dx, prompt2
     int 21h

     lea di, InputWord
     mov ah, 0Ah
     mov dx, di
     int 21h

     ;To check if the length of substring is shorter than the main string
     mov cl, [si+1]
     mov ch, 0
     add si, cx
     mov bl, [di+1]
     mov bh, 0
     cmp bx, cx
     ja invalid_length
     je valid
     jb matching

valid:
     cld
     repe cmpsb
     je found_display
     jne notfound_display

matching:
     mov al, [si]
     mov ah, [di]
     cmp al, ah
     je check
     jne iterate

iterate:  
     inc si
     mov dx, strlen
     dec dx
     cmp dx, 0
     je notfound_display
     jmp matching

check:
     mov cl, [di+1]
     mov ch, 0
     mov ax, si
     add ax, 1
     cld
     repe cmpsb
     jne again
     jmp found_display

again:
     mov si, ax    
     dec dx
     lea di, InputWord
     jmp matching


invalid_length:
     mov ah, 09h
     lea dx, invalid
     int 21h
```

Comment: "I don't know how to use a debugger" learn it! We aren't born knowing that either. In fact that should have been one of the first steps. Given that this is dos code, turbo debugger which has a text based menu system should take about 2 minutes to learn. Anyway, `add si, cx` is really suspicious. Since you haven't commented it, it's unclear what you even wanted to do with that.

Comment: Using a debugger is an excellent way to learn assembly language.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> strlen dw ($-InputWord)
> ```

This does nothing useful. The length that it calculate can not help you in any way!

> ```
> ;To check if the length of substring is shorter than the main string
>  mov cl, [si+1]
>  mov ch, 0
>  add si, cx
>  mov bl, [di+1]
>  mov bh, 0
>  cmp bx, cx
> ```

Here (as Jester told you) the `add si, cx` instruction is wrong. You need `add si, 2` to set `SI` to the start of the string. You will also need to add `add di, 2` to set `DI` to the start of the word. Do this and the *valid* part of your program will work correctly.

---

#### For the *matching* part:

Consider the case where the string has 7 characters and the word that you're looking for has 6 characters. You can find the word in at most 2 ways.

Consider the case where the string has 8 characters and the word that you're looking for has 6 characters. You can find the word in at most 3 ways.

Consider the case where the string has 9 characters and the word that you're looking for has 6 characters. You can find the word in at most 4 ways.

Notice the regularity? The number of possible finds is equal to the difference in length plus 1.

```
    mov     bp, cx      ;CX is length string (long)
    sub     bp, bx      ;BX is length word  (short)
    inc     bp
```

This sets `BP` to the number of tries in your *matching* routine.

```
    cld
    lea     si, [InputString + 2]
    lea     di, [InputWord + 2]
matching:
    mov     al, [si]    ;Next character from the string
    cmp     al, [di]    ;Always the first character from the word
    je      check
continue:  
    inc     si          ;DI remains at start of the word
    dec     bp
    jnz     matching    ;More tries to do
    jmp     notfound_display
```

The *check* part will use `repe cmpsb` to test for a match, but in the event that the match is not found, you must be able to return to the *matching* code at the *continue* label. You have to preserve the registers.

```
check:
    push    si
    push    di
    mov     cx, bx     ;BX is length of word
    repe cmpsb
    pop     di
    pop     si
    jne     continue
    jmp     found_display
```